# Problem while importing pyplot in windows, jupyter gives unexpected keyword error.

Tags: python-3.x, windows, matplotlib, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

The error is related to the unexpected keyword argument 'exist_ok'. I tried many solutions online. Before it was showing error 'DLL failed to load properly', then after trying many solutions, this error appeared.

```
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-cae538ef789d> in <module>()
----> 1 get_ipython().magic('matplotlib')
      2 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

D:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py in magic(self, arg_s)
   2158         magic_name, _, magic_arg_s = arg_s.partition(' ')
   2159         magic_name = magic_name.lstrip(prefilter.ESC_MAGIC)
-> 2160         return self.run_line_magic(magic_name, magic_arg_s)
   2161 
   2162     #-------------------------------------------------------------------------

D:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py in run_line_magic(self, magic_name, line)
   2079                 kwargs['local_ns'] = sys._getframe(stack_depth).f_locals
   2080             with self.builtin_trap:
-> 2081                 result = fn(*args,**kwargs)
   2082             return result
   2083 

<decorator-gen-106> in matplotlib(self, line)

D:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\IPython\core\magic.py in <lambda>(f, *a, **k)
    186     # but it's overkill for just that one bit of state.
    187     def magic_deco(arg):
--> 188         call = lambda f, *a, **k: f(*a, **k)
    189 
    190         if callable(arg):

D:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\IPython\core\magics\pylab.py in matplotlib(self, line)
     98             print("Available matplotlib backends: %s" % backends_list)
     99         else:
--> 100             gui, backend = self.shell.enable_matplotlib(args.gui)
    101             self._show_matplotlib_backend(args.gui, backend)
    102 

D:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py in enable_matplotlib(self, gui)
   2964                 gui, backend = pt.find_gui_and_backend(self.pylab_gui_select)
   2965 
-> 2966         pt.activate_matplotlib(backend)
   2967         pt.configure_inline_support(self, backend)
   2968 

D:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\IPython\core\pylabtools.py in activate_matplotlib(backend)
    312     matplotlib.rcParams['backend'] = backend
    313 
--> 314     import matplotlib.pyplot
    315     matplotlib.pyplot.switch_backend(backend)
    316 

C:\Users\sb\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py in <module>()
     30 from cycler import cycler
     31 import matplotlib
---> 32 import matplotlib.colorbar
     33 import matplotlib.image
     34 from matplotlib import rcsetup, style

C:\Users\sb\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\colorbar.py in <module>()
     30 import matplotlib.collections as collections
     31 import matplotlib.colors as colors
---> 32 import matplotlib.contour as contour
     33 import matplotlib.cm as cm
     34 import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

C:\Users\sb\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\contour.py in <module>()
     16 import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
     17 import matplotlib.collections as mcoll
---> 18 import matplotlib.font_manager as font_manager
     19 import matplotlib.text as text
     20 import matplotlib.cbook as cbook

C:\Users\sb\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\font_manager.py in <module>()
   1335     _fmcache = None
   1336 
-> 1337     cachedir = get_cachedir()
   1338     if cachedir is not None:
   1339         _fmcache = os.path.join(

C:\Users\sb\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py in wrapper()
    411         nonlocal called, ret
    412         if not called:
--> 413             ret = func()
    414             called = True
    415             _log.debug(fmt, ret)

C:\Users\sb\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py in get_cachedir()
    651     _get_config_dir, except using `$XDG_CACHE_HOME`/`~/.cache` instead.
    652     """
--> 653     return _get_config_or_cache_dir(_get_xdg_cache_dir())
    654 
    655 

C:\Users\sb\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py in _get_config_or_cache_dir(xdg_base)
    613     if configdir:
    614         try:
--> 615             configdir.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
    616         except OSError:
    617             pass

TypeError: mkdir() got an unexpected keyword argument 'exist_ok'
```

I am using python 3.7 in Windows. I am running the jupyter project. However, I am not able to run pyplot because of the above mentioned error. I haven't found any working solutions till now. Importing matplotlib works fine, but only the pyplot doesn't work at all.

Comment: You are running the code in python 2.7 (as seen by the path `D:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\...`). If you want to use matplotlib with python 2.7 you need to install matplotlib 2.2.3 or lower.

Comment: Hello, I reinstalled matplotlib version 2.2.3, but I got an error again,  'DLL load failed and specific module not found'.

Comment: You have at least 2 versions of python installed; probably you are using the one where you didn't install matplotlib.

Comment: Oh, yes that was the problem. Thank you.